# Android ndk-build error while integrating with tesseract

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, cygwin, tesseract

I have searched a lot but no one is getting this  error (see screenshot below).

[image: NDK BUILD ERROR]

I am using OpenCV and Tesseract for my project.

I have imported both of them as module and now when i am trying to build NDK it is  giving  error even I have installed Cygwin with MAKE package.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Solution  found actually i had downloaded cygwin and  make of 64 bit while my computer is 32 bit.